# Web Worker Initialisation Crash without Error

Tags: javascript, web-worker

When I create a faulty web worker, it immediately terminates. *However*, the browser console does not show any error messages, which is strange.

This seems to be reproducible both in Firefox and Chrome.

```js
let code = `
import { crash } from "./nowhere.js"; 
console.log("hi"); // Never gets executed
`;

let alternateCode = `
console.log("hi");
throw new Error("normal errors do show up in the browser console");
`;

let blob = new Blob([code], {
            type: 'application/javascript'
        });

let blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
let worker = new Worker(blobURL, {type: "module"});
worker.onmessage = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
};
worker.postMessage("start");

// And check out the browser console
```

Comment: ... I'm a bit torn by that self-answer. At least for Chrome, the main issue is that you are trying to use an `import` statement in a classic-worker. So it's a really particular case of an issue for one to meet and is not related to the broken module at all, but really to the SyntaxError `import {` creates. If your worker was initialized correctly as a module worker, then you'd have a "Failed to load module script" error in the console. Firefox however is still silent on the broken module even when loaded as a module-worker.

Comment: @Kaiido Ah, thank you. I forgot to create the web worker as a module web worker, absolutely silly mistake on my part. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

This only happens with **faulty ES Module imports**, and is caused by https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1872483 and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1215587 .

The error can be caught with a simple `onerror` listener. However, do note that the error message does not contain useful information in any browser.

```js
let code = `
import { crash } from "./nowhere.js"; 
console.log("hi"); // Never gets executed
`;

let alternateCode = `
console.log("hi");
throw new Error("normal errors do show up in the browser console");
`;

let blob = new Blob([code], {
        type: 'application/javascript'
    });

let blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
let worker = new Worker(blobURL, {type: "module"});
worker.onerror = (data) => {
    console.error(data);
};
worker.onmessage = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
};
worker.postMessage("start");

// And check out the browser console
```